# Redis Cluster in multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, redis, thread-safety, connection-pooling, jedis

Im currently using Redis Cluster Mode with 3 master instances, i'm using Jedis(Java client) in listening server which every data received i create a new thread then the thread make an update in redis.

My question is how can i use Redis Cluster instance in multiple thread with pool configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JedisCluster is thread-safe. 
It contains JedisPool for each node  internally, so you don't need to worry about dealing JedisCluster instance with multithread.

Comment: Thank you so much i just tested it and it worked perfectly without any problem.